# Python - looping through a dictionary of hyperlinks

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

This Python Selenium script checks if an item on a particular website is in stock or out of stock. The script currently checked one link at a time.

I'd now like the script to check multiple hyperlinks (stored in a dict) rather than just one hyperlink.

How do I get it to cycle through the links one after another?

```
import ...

from links import my_links  #this is my dictionary of links

URL = my_links['link1'] #start at the first hyperlink in the dictionary
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.39 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
#chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized");
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]);
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False);

#Check for stock
def stock_check():
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        stockQuery = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "add-to-basket-btn"}) #looks for add to cart button
        if stockQuery:
            break
        else:
            print('Item not available.')
            time.sleep(300)
    print('Item available.')
stock_check()
exit()
```

This is my dictionary of the links

```
my_links = {
    'link1': '<<item link here>>',
    'link2': '<<item link here>>',
    'link3': '<<item link here>>',
    'link4': '<<item link here>>',
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the function `stock_check()` to include a URL parameter. Then, iterate python `dict` using `.items()`:

```
#Check for stock
def stock_check(URL):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        stockQuery = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "add-to-basket-btn"}) #looks for add to cart button
        if stockQuery:
            break
        else:
            print('Item not available.')
            time.sleep(300)
            return 
    print('Item available.')

for key, URL in my_links.items():
    print("ID:", key, "Link:", URL)
    stock_check(URL)
exit()
```

Comment: thanks, this kind of worked - it iterates through the dictionary if all items are in stock but if link1 is out of stock then it keeps looping on item 1 and never tries item 2-10. I'd like it to loop through all of the items 1 - 10 and then start the loop all over again. How do i change this please?

Comment: Just add a `return`. I have edited the answer. Have a look. Note: I don't know exactly what you are trying to do here. If you give me more details on that, I can probably modify your function to get your desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I would never have known about the Return. It works just as expected, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `keys()` method helps it's an iterable that helps you to cycle through all the keys in your dictionary.

With `keys()` method:

```py
for link in my_links.keys():
    URL = my_links[link] #start at the first hyperlink in the dictionary
...
```

You could use also the `values()` method and the `items()` method. The `values()` method cycles through all the values of your dictionary

With the `values()` method:

```py
for link in my_links.values():
    URL = link #start at the first hyperlink in the dictionary
...
```

The `items()` method cycles through all the keys and values of your dictionary.

With the `items()` method:

```py
for key,link in my_links.items():
    URL = my_links[key] # Option 1
    URL = link # Option2
...
```